# Как добавить комментирование в HTML сайтах (чтобыдругие люди могли написать отзыв и он отображался на сайте) понадобится другой язык программирования?

Tags: html, комментарии

помогите пж как добавить комментирование для других пользователей сайта (типо оставить отзыв) а то мне оч надо) А то я уверен что понадобится другой язык. Других к сожалению кроме HTML не знаю (и то плохо знаю ели на джуниора тяну)

Comment: Только с помощью HTML нельзя. Продолжайте учить и когда дойдете до js подумайте об этой задачи снова.

Comment: А пока этот вопрос слишком неуклюжий. Посоветовал бы вам удалить его.

Comment: Можете использовать [Disqus](https://disqus.com/). HTML -- не язык программирования, а язык разметки.